# Get part of path of all files within some directory and subdirectories

Tags: php, laravel

I am retrieving all files using `Illuminate\Support\Facades\File`:

```
    $files = File::allFiles(base_path('resources/views/emails'));
    foreach($files as $file) {
        $file_name = $file->getBasename('.blade.php');
        $path_info = $file->getPathInfo();

        $template = substr($path_info, strpos($path_info, 'emails/') + 7).'.'.$file_name;
        $template = str_replace('/', '.', $template);
    }
```

Inside `emails` directory there are more subdirectories with some containing another directory inside. I would like to get all file names, without extension, but with names of subdirectories the file is stored in. I would also like to omit everything before emails directory (including emails itself) from path name.

Example:
`resources/views/emails/subfolder_one/subfolder_two/myfile.blade.php`

Expected output: `subfolder_one.subfolder_two.myfile`

The way I did it works, but seems too complicated. Is there a function which would reduce number of lines of code withing `foreach` loop?

Comment: What, less than a get a loop and 4 lines of code?

Comment: I agree, I just wanted to know if there is some function similar to `getPathInfo()` that returns just part of a path, the part I need? Similar to `getBasename()`, if I could pass as parameter what I want to omit in path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if it's always your folder start from `emails` you may explode  the path to the array and for loop at index 3 and concatenate result with `"."`

```
$str = 'resources/views/emails/subfolder_one/subfolder_two/myfile.blade.php';
$str_arr = explode('/', $str);
$template = '';
for ($i = 3; $i < count($str_arr); $i++) {
    $template .= $str_arr[$i] . '.';
}
dd($template);
```

Comment: That's nice! Thanks